# How to create listening animation like SoundHound or TrackID

Tags: android, animation

I want to create an app that records a sound. And while the app is recording the sound, I want an animation that looks just like in SoundHound or TrackID app.

I'm wondering what's the best and easiest way to do this? Is it using a Canvas, Animation-List, or GIFs?

Thanks

Comment: isn't my answer useful to you? no reply no response.

Comment: sorry, I haven't been online last night. Yes it's a solution to my problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try **[ProgressWheel](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel)**.

[image]

You can simply put another `ImageView` over this to display your custom image.

**Edit**

Another option I found is RaghavSood's [AndroidCircularSeekBar](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar)

[image]

[Advanced document](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar/blob/master/USAGE.md#usage) is also there.